# No sound from emulator

Tags: visual-studio, audio, android-emulator, android-studio-bumblebee

After upgrading Android studio to Bumblebee (Windows) I get no sound from emulators in PC laptop speakers running Visual Studio Code but have sound in Bluetooth headphones. Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: have you researched this ?   its a common challenge I suspect with solutions abound

Comment: Yes I have searched and researched for three days but in vain. If you know it to be a common problem, do you also know a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often before the problem was my inexperience. The emulator sound can be turn on in  Windows  **Advanced sound options**, by default it is off.